# Cleartext traffic is permitted by default in Flutter application

Tags: android, flutter, dart

According to the Android documentation, apps that target API level 28 or higher has property `usesCleartextTraffic` set by default to `false`.
When the attribute is set to false, platform components, for example, `HTTP` and `FTP` stacks, `DownloadManager`, and `MediaPlayer`, refuse the app's requests to use cleartext traffic.

I'm developing a Flutter application which targets API level 32, that means by default it shouldn't be able to use cleartext traffic. However, app is still using cleartext traffic. I don't understand why this is happening.

Regardless the default value for `usesCleartextTraffic`, I tried to set it manually in `AndroidManifest.xml` file in the `android/app/src/main` folder like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest ...>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <application
    ...
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="false"
    ...>
    ...
</application>
</manifest>
```

It didn't work.

I have also tried to use network security config, so I created the file in `res/xml/network_security_config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="false">
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
</network-security-config>
```

and set a reference in `AndroidManifest.xml` like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest ...>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<application ...>
  ...
  <meta-data android:name="io.flutter.network-policy"
             android:resource="@xml/network_security_config"/>
</application>
</manifest>
```

It didn't work also.

Flutter doctor output :

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.3.10, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.1105], locale en-US)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.1.0-rc1)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.1.5)
[√] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
[√] VS Code (version 1.77.3)
[√] Connected device (4 available)
[√] HTTP Host Availability
```

**I can't prevent cleartext traffic in my application.**

I still can make API calls to non-HTTPS endpoint and get response successfully instead of getting an exception `Cleartext HTTP traffic to <url> is not permitted`. like

```
try {
 final response = await get(Uri.parse('http://<url>')); 
 print(response.body); 
} catch (e) { 
 print(e);
}
```

Comment: Can you give a example of what clear text traffic still works (including the code that executes it)?

Comment: I can still make API calls to non-HTTPS endpoint and get response successfully instead of getting an exception "Cleartext HTTP traffic to <url> is not permitted". like

  try {
    final response = await get(Uri.parse('http://<url>'));
    print(response.body);
  } catch (e) {
    print(e);
  }
@Robert

Comment: Please don't post code in comments, edit your question instead and add it there, properly formatted.